# Apache <LocationMatch> regEx field

Tags: regex, apache

I can't seem to set regex correctly for the  directive.

The syntax is:

```
<LocationMatch regex> ... </LocationMatch>
```

I've tried many of the following to no avail:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(admin-media|connect|css|downloads|images|images-web|js)/.+$">
<LocationMatch "^/(admin-media|connect|css|downloads|images|images-web|js)/.+">
<LocationMatch "/(admin-media|connect|css|downloads|images|images-web|js)/.+$">
<LocationMatch "/(admin-media|connect|css|downloads|images|images-web|js)/.">
```

Basically, I'm trying to override my default handler to None for addresses that match http://mysite/css/anything, but with no luck!

I could try setting up <Location "/admin">, and so forth, but that's just bloating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you really sure that your problem is with the LocationMatch directive? All your examples seem perfectly valid to me. I suspect that you are barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: your right, I was barking up the wrong tree! I hade two v-host entries that really look alike, I was editing the handler for one app and testing it out on a completely different one and it never worked!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the regex is actually executed when placed inside a string ("") or is it treated as a literal?

Comment: The syntax kRON is using works for me. And the docs are pretty clear on this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting this in your .htaccess file or your global config file?  The .htaccess file can't do LocationMatch

Answer (score -4):

Do you have "RewriteEngine on" inside your VirtualHost directive? (and mod_rewrite enabled)

Comment: `mod_rewrite` has nothing to do with `<LocationMatch>`